# Lifetime gets smaller after extracting method

Tags: rust, lifetime, borrow-checker

I had a lifetime problem on extracting a method in Rust. Following is a minimal example:

```
pub struct Obj {
    value: usize,
}

pub struct Container<'a> {
    content: &'a Obj,
}

pub struct Props<'a> {
    att: Container<'a>,
}

impl <'a> Props<'a> {
    pub fn value(&self) -> usize {
        self.att.content.value
    }
}
```

This works fine with:

```
pub fn test<'a>(properties: Props<'a>) -> impl (Fn() -> usize) + 'a {
    || properties.att.content.value
}
```

but gives an error for:

```
pub fn test<'a>(properties: Props<'a>) -> impl (Fn() -> usize) + 'a {
    || properties.value()
}
```

`closure may outlive the current function, but it borrows 'properties', which is owned by the current function`

I think I understand this error message, but I do not understand why the first piece of code does compile. Isn't `properties` borrowed also in the first example?

Could this problem be solved by putting some lifetimes to the function `value()`?

[Link to Rust Playground Example](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=1c8284452f9cc2c4d38ab6fa32ebfb6a)

Comment: Can you provide the real [mre] please? The first example produces the exact same error.

Comment: You can test it in the playground - first works, second does not. Maybe a rust compiler version problem?

Comment: Interesting, it does [not work on godbolt](https://rust.godbolt.org/z/jcGMe4Tzf)

Comment: @cafce25 Probably because the playground runs in the latest (2021) edition, whereas godbolt runs rustc directly, which defaults to the earliest (2015) edition. Edition 2021 changed closure capture rules to borrow a narrower part of the value.

Comment: May this be some effect of NLL or Polonius?

Comment: Add `move` before the closure and then it works. The closure captures a reference when it (thinks it) can get away with doing so, which doesn't work here. The example without the method call works because as of edition 2021 closures capture the last part of the expression, and since that's `usize`, it apparently just gets moved into the closure automatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since edition 2021 [closures are allowed to borrow only part of a struct](https://doc.rust-lang.org/edition-guide/rust-2021/disjoint-capture-in-closures.html) so your first example is allowed to borrow only part of it namely `properties.att.content.value` which is behind a reference of appropriate lifetime for the closure you're returning.
The second example does not see it only needs that part so it has to borrow the full `properties`, but that is dropped at the end of the function, so you can't return a closure referencing it.

To make the second example work just follow the compilers recommendation, add a `move` before the closure, that moves `properties` inside the closure so it can safely be returned.

```rust
pub fn test<'a>(properties: Props<'a>) -> impl (Fn() -> usize) + 'a {
    move || properties.value()
}
```

Comment: I just added another function `calltest` to the [example](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=531b30ed18424c62943a3b8824b24cd5). In this example the closure that accesses `properties` will live longer than `properties` - and compile! I would expect this to be a problem ...

Comment: `properties` never lived as long as the closure in the first example, but the reference inside is valid for `'a` so it's fine to take a reference to anything behind it for as long as `'a`

Comment: From my point of view there is a difference in querying `properties.att.content.value` at call time or in capturing a reference to it and just dereference it at call time. The first would have failed if properties was dropped meanwhile. I assume that this behavior is only valid for shared (read-only) references, so one could argue that at least the value could not change meanwhile.

Comment: No a mutable reference would work as well since your function has it so no one else can modify it. And no the first doesn't fail since the reference object of `content` can't have been dropped since you told the compiler it has to live as long as the closure (the lifetime `'a`)